# Problems with Seaborn Category Plot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, error-handling, seaborn

I have a dataframe that looks somewhat like this:

```
data = [{"x" : "john", "y" : 0.0997, "hue" : 'cat. 1'},
            {"x" : "john", "y" : 0.2337, "hue" : 'cat. 1'}, 
            {"x" : "lisa", "y" : 0.1997, "hue" : 'cat. 2'},
            {"x" : "lisa", "y" : 0.9957, "hue" : 'cat. 3'},
            {"x" : "john", "y" : 0.8197, "hue" : 'cat. 2'}]

data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I try to plot a `seaborn` category plot:

```
sns.catplot(x=data.x, y=data.y, hue=data.hue, size=8, data=data)
```

A plot is actually returned - but with weird axes and along with an error message:

[image]

The error I get is:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I played arround with the margins. But the only improvement I got is the error:

`ValueError: left cannot be >= right`

What am I doing wrong? How can I solve the issue/issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to follow the proper syntax. Just Pass the column name to x and y parameters. This will solve your problem.
[Link](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) for the same.

---

```
sns.catplot(x='x', y='y', hue='hue', data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you! Great, easy, and quick answer!